# Any way to speed up evaluation in an Animate?

Tags: plotting, animation, performance-tuning

I have a self-defined function which is fairly complicated and gives the analytical form. The result contains two independent variables. I use `Animate` to plot the function by enumerating one parameter.

```
myfun[x_, y_] := ... (* here are some complicate calculation *)
Animate[Plot[myfun[x, y], {x, 0, 2.5}], {y, 0, 5.0, 0.5}]
```

Each plot in the `Animate` will call myfun each time it needs a value from it, that's why the animation runs slowly. I don't know how to speed up code. But now, I run myfun once, copy the resulting expression and paste it to make a new function

```
myfun[x_, y_] := ... (* here are some complicate calculation *)
(* here it returns some expression and I copy and paste it into myfun2 *) 
myfun2[x1_, y1_] := EXPRESSION_FROM_PASTE /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}
Animate[Plot[myfun2[x, y], {x, 0, 2.5}], {y, 0, 5.0, 0.5}]
```

It runs pretty fast now. But if I change some parameter or math in myfun, I need to copy and paste the function again to make myfun2. Is that anyway to achieve that programatically? Thanks.

Comment: Search this site for "memoization", specially Leonid's answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has nothing to do with memorization as mentioned by @belisarius in the comment. I'm not sure what kind of complicated calculation you have in `myfun`, but if you expect to get a more concise/simpler expression from `myfun` and then assign it to `myfun2` for further manipulation, a slightly better way to go without manually copy and paste is

```
myfun[x_, y_] := ... (* here is your complicated calculation *)
myfun2[x1_, y1_] := Evaluate[myfun[x, y]/.{x->x1, y->y1}//Simplify]
```

or even a simpler one (just one-line)

```
myfun3[x_, y_] := Evaluate[...(* here is your complicated calculation in myfun *)//Simplify]
```

which forces the right hand side to be evaluated first and then be assigned to `myfun3`. Note that I assume `Simplify` could somehow simplify the analytical expression obtained from the calculation. Given the description of your text, I assume this answers more or less your question?

Comment: Thanks Fang. Yes, Evaluate is really what I am looking for